# CharAt with Buttontext doesnt work

Tags: android, charat

I want to get a char from the second position of a String, but the app always crashes.

```
String pdf = "Hallo";
    char w = pdf.charAt(1);
    btn1.setText(w);
```

why does this not work, and how can i make it better :)?

Comment: Have you got a valid reference to btn1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String toTextButton = String.valueOf(w);
btn1.setText(toTextButton);
```